# Unable to fetch nested data from realtime database of firebase in firebase recycler view

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am trying to fetch data from firebase database and show it in recycler view, it works perfectly fine when there is no nested data but doesn't work with nested data, please help me I am attaching all the screenshots here.

JSON uploaded on firebase:

```
{
  "orders": {
    "order1": {
        "Customer": "Ankit",
        "Description": "Make it spicy",
        "Food": {
            "Paneer": {
                "Full_Plate": 1,
                "Half_Plate": 1
            },
            "Roti": {
                "Full_Plate": 1,
                "Half_Plate": 2
            }
        },
        "Header": "table1"
    },
    "order2": {
        "Customer": "Raghav",
        "Description": "Creamy",
        "Food": {
            "Chicken": {
                "Full_Plate": 1,
                "Half_Plate": 1
            }
        },
        "Header": "Table2"
    }
  }
}
```

My `onCreateView()` code

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recfragment, container, false);
            recview=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recview);
            recview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
            FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Model> options=
                    new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Model>()
                            .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("orders"),Model.class)
                            .build();
            myAdapter=new MyAdapter(options);
            recview.setAdapter(myAdapter);
            return view;

        }
```

Model class code:

```
public class Model {
    String Customer,Description,Header;
    HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>> Food;

    public Model(){

    }

    public Model(String customer, String description, String header, HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> food) {
        Customer = customer;
        Description = description;
        Header = header;
        Food = food;
    }

    public String getCustomer() {
        return Customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(String customer) {
        Customer = customer;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        Description = description;
    }

    public String getHeader() {
        return Header;
    }

    public void setHeader(String header) {
        Header = header;
    }

    public HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> getFood() {
        return Food;
    }

    public void setFood(HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> food) {
        Food = food;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase uses JavaBean convention to determine the property names in the JSON. This means that a method like `public String getCustomer()` translates to a property `customer` in the database. Notice the difference in casing there? That's most likely the cause of your problems.

If you want to maintain the casing you have in your database, you can put annotations on your Java class to explicitly specify the property names:

```
@PropertyName("Customer")
public String getCustomer() {
    return Customer;
}

@PropertyName("Customer")
public void setCustomer(String customer) {
    Customer = customer;
}
```

You'll need to do this for every getter/setter where the name/case in the database doesn't exactly match the name/casing in the Java class.

Comment: Thanks, sir for replying but that's not my issue. In Jason data, there is a field with the name "food" and inside "food" we have "Paneer" and "Roti". My data is in such a way that next time it can be "Chicken" or anything under "food". So I don't know what will be the name and data is nested. I want to fetch this type of data, please help.

Comment: For that problem, you might want to try using. a `HashMap<String, Object>`, as I think Firebase may have a problem mapping to the more specific `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>`.

Comment: Yes, sir, that is exactly my issue. In the documentation it's written you can use SnapshotParser but don't know how to use it. Thanks for your time sir.

Comment: If you use a `HashMap<String, Object>`, you shouldn't need a custom parser. If you want a custom parser, look at some of these for inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebaseui%5D+SnapshotParser+%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D?

Comment: Okay thank you so much, will take a look at it for sure.